# How to acess array element jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm passsing an array List to view from controller. and i got this as result:

[image: array model]

Then I want to access that array (data) to insert consultant name in a variable, how can i do it?
thanks

```
function LoadVisual() {
        $.when(LoadVisualAjax()).then((data) => {
            DrawChart(data);
            document.getElementById('viewbagLabel').textContent = data[1]; ???????
        }
```

Comment: document.getElementById('viewbagLabel').textContent = data[1].Consultant_Name;
pls notice that you only will add the Consultant Name of the second object from your data array